# laravel custom auth - attempt(), session

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm learning how to create custom auth system. I created own guard Player. On my test function I'm usimg attempt() to authenticate user. Checking is passed. Then I created test2 method which is accesible only for logged user.

My **Route** is:

```
Route::get('test', 'MyController@test');
Route::get('test2', 'MyController@test2')->middleware('auth');
```

My **Controller** is:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        $cr = ['name' => 'pl', 'password' => 'pl'];

        if (Auth::guard('player')->attempt($cr)) {
            $user = Auth::guard('player')->user();
            return 'ok';
        }

        return 'not found';
    }

    public function test2()
    {
        return 'test2';
    }
}
```

My **guard config** is:

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'player' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'player',
        ],

        'club' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'club',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'player' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Player::class,
        ],

        'club' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Club::class,
        ],
    ],
```

I want to get access to test2 route by hand (not by redirecting) after performing test function but I can't. I'm receiving Auth default login form.

Should I write my own middleware or set session manually? Please help.

Comment: can you post the 'player' guard config ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write you own middleware,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RedirectIfNotPlayer
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'player')
    {
        if(!auth()->guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(url('/player/login'));
        }

        return $next($request);

    }
}
```

add this middleware to your `kernel.php` file, inside `routeMiddleware`,

```
'player' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotPlayer::class,
```

Then You can use your middleware in route,

```
Route::get('test2', 'MyController@test2')->middleware('player');
```

Comment: Your solution is not working. IWhen I'm executing test2 route after test I'm redirecting to player login form. In test2 Auth::check() always return false. I'm wondering why.

Comment: @appson Did you update all of your code like i suggested ?

Comment: Yes. I created middleware by artisan and for rest I made copy-paste. I'm wondering why Auth::check() always return false in test2.

Comment: It should work. You can see this tutorial for more information : https://scotch.io/@sukelali/how-to-create-multi-table-authentication-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do like this may be this work out!

```
public function test()
{
    $cr = ['name' => 'pl', 'password' => 'pl'];

    if (Auth::guard('player')->attempt($cr)) {
        $user = Auth::guard('player')->user();
        return 'ok';
redirect("test2(view)");
    }
```

Comment: I know but I' don't want to make redirection. I want to do it by hand. Firstly I want to type test url on my keyboard, and then test2 url.

Comment: Yes. I'm testing different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect to somewhere after login is successful to have the session persist.

Answer (score 0):

make `auth` middleware use your guard:

```
Route::get('test2', 'MyController@test2')->middleware('auth:player');
```